# Dojo JS array to Json String

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I' trying to convert a array with some other arrays nested in it into a json string, by means of dojox.json.ref.toJson method.

However, when calling the method in which this is done, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined".

I' not sure if a require statement is needed as I' new to Dojo.

javascript Code:

```
function ajaxPOST(uRL, parameters) {

    console.log(parameters); 

    var json = dojox.json.ref.toJson(parameters);

      var xhrArgs = {
                      url: uRL,
                      postData: json,
                      handleAs: "text",
                      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
                      load: function(data) {

                      },
                      error: function(error) {

                      }
                  };


      var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
}
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided sample, I'm assuming you're using the legacy loader with globals, rather than the newer AMD style.

Do you explicitly need to use `dojox.json.ref`?  Does your JSON array have linked references?  If not, you can just use `dojo.toJson`.

If you do need to use dojox.json.ref, then you'll need to require it:

```
dojo.require('dojox.json.ref');
```

Documentation on `dojox.json.ref` can be found [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/json/ref.html).  You might want to read up on [dojo.require](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/require.html) and when it is needed also.

Comment: Yes, it has the said references. My doubt concernsthe implementation of the require statement within the already existing function.
I've tried many ways but cant seem to get it right.
Could you give me an example?
Btw, I'm using dojo 1.9.1

Comment: Are you using AMD (`async:1` config, lots of `require(['dojo/something/somethingelse],function(something){})` statements in your code?    Or are you using the legacy sync loader with exposed globals?

Comment: I dont think I'm using any of them, I'm  pretty new to Dojo, only started working with it today.

Comment: If you’re just starting, you shouldn’t be using any of the legacy syntax. Read the [hello dojo tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hello_dojo/).